# Placeholder in Symfony annotation translation message

Tags: symfony, assert

I'm using Symfony with annotation and assert to do some validation checks in a form. With the following annotation I'm checking if a field is not blank:

```
@Assert\NotBlank(message="not_blank")
```

This generated a message in the correct language, this case:

> The field cannot be empty

Now I want to add the field name as a placeholer so I don't need to make a separate message for every field. So something like:

```
@Assert\NotBlank(message="not_blank {{ name=email }}")

   <trans-unit id="1">
    <source>not_blank</source>
    <target>This {{ name }} field cannot be empty</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

In the translation file it would then be:

Then I can output:

> The email field cannot be empty

If this is possible then I don't need to make separate message for every field like: name, email, street etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open **@Assert\NotBlank** you can see:

```
class NotBlank extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This value should not be blank.';
}
```

So you can't use it in another way, but you can create custom constraint by extending the base constraint class [Constraint](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.html)

See [Tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)